# See number of views for a posted question

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, views

I am using the iOS Stack Overflow app. I often use the app on the go to view answers to the question I have posted. I also use it to post new questions whenever something pops up in my mind when I am on the go.

And as a curious Stack Overflow user, I like to monitor the progress of my questions. One way to do that is see the number of views for my questions. But unfortunately, I don't see this stat on the Stack Overflow iOS app.

I therefore request you to update the app to show the number of views for a question when you visit that question on the app.

I would also like to take this opportunity to ask you to make the app full screen for iPhone X onwards! Utilizing the whole viewport will definitely give a better user experience.

Comment: @Glorfindel awesome, we both found a different dupe ... do we need to dupe the others as well?

Comment: It'd be even more awesome if one of us had a hammer, but mine is only 80% charged :(

Comment: @Glorfindel No problem; I had a Stormbreaker Axe. I dupe'd the dupe.

Comment: Well my request also talks about having a full screen view. Anyhow, I am surprised that even after 4 years of posting the original request, this feature is not available on the iOS app! Does a feature require some minimum upvotes to be taken for development? Or the iOS development has been completely halted?

Comment: @maverick iOS development is completely halted

Comment: That's sad. Maybe we should open (and upvote) a new thread to re-start iOS development!

Comment: It's more a question of funding I imagine. Are you willing to pay to have the iOS app updated?

Comment: Oh. I thought it was more of a priority related issue. @RobertLongson Do you work for Stackoverflow?

Comment: No I've never worked there. I've just read a lot of the Q&A here.